# Rails CSV Initial Import and Appending More Rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, time-series

I just want some good advice on how to go about storing time-series data like what is shown below that I will upload into my web application using Ruby on Rails.

```
    time,temp,humid
    11-13-2013 12:24:24, 88, 55
    11-13-2013 12:24:29, 89, 54
    11-13-2013 12:24:34, 88, 55
    11-13-2013 12:24:39, 88, 55
```

I'm creating a data collection web application that has many users.  I created a directory like structure for users to store their data tables on.  However, since I'm using Rails I'm thinking that I should use an `ActiveRecord` model to store the individual columns in the data table as separate instances, so that the entire data table is made up of many instances of data column models?  Or should I use `ActiveRecord` to store the entire data table?

Also, how would I append more rows once it has been stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you choose any persistence layer, you should think about what will you do with this data. If it is some sampling data (time series), I think you will do some charts / aggregation on this data.

SQL is pretty fine for grouping or suming data together, but if you want some fancy queries and the data is huge, you will get performance loss.

If it is the case, I would suggest check out the aggregation framework from MongoDB, but keep in mind it is not so easy to setup a proper MongoDB instalation ready for production use.

Since you learn Rails, I would suggest, use any kind of SQL for the first run via ActiveRecord.

For reading and parsing CSV use FasterCSV and you will be fine.

Comment: Okay so I was thinking of using an ActiveRecord Model to store an entire user-defined data table within the database. So the user has the ability to somewhat do database migrations.  What would be the best way to achieve this?

I thought of some ways, that seem quite messy.

Comment: You should store one CSV row per one Database Record. First, create the model, don't think about the CSV stuff at all yet, add validations, for example a valid date, time validation, and a range validation,for the sample data, if different users can save their CVSs, you should also add a user_id tho the database. When this works, I mean you can add, edit, or remove records from the database via console, go ahead with the CSV parsing stuff.

Comment: Maybe you're not aware of this, but ActiveRecord is not only the name of a Library for the RubyOnRails Framework, but it is also a Design Pattern, http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ActiveRecord .